# Screen Responsiveness

Tags: responsiveness

I have a problem with the responsiveness of the project I'm working on. Each time I zoom out, the contents of the page displaces instead of just becoming smaller and staying in order. Can anyone help me with what I can do to make it better? I usually have this problem with anything I'm building.
Here's the Github repo to the project https://github.com/Lilianada/TTA here's the live version https://lilianada.github.io/TTA/

Comment: That could help you: https://www.google.se/amp/s/webdevpuneet.com/how-to-disable-pinch-and-zoom-on-mobile-web-page/amp/

Answer (score 0):

I literally just solved this. I'm a newbie btw. Using CSS Grid to place contents makes everything work perfectly. I'll definitely write a blog post on this. This helped https://classroom.udacity.com/nanodegrees/nd0011/dashboard/overview